# Flutter Unable to load assets json

Tags: json, flutter, dart, assets, snapshot

I was create Card post in [] by call another file but when i run it wasn't  show Data.

```
class FeedScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final Future<List<Story>> futureListOfStory;
  final Future<List<Post>> futureListOfPost;
  const FeedScreen({
    Key key,
    @required this.futureListOfStory,
    @required this.futureListOfPost,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size _screen = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: _screen.height,
        width: _screen.width,
        child: ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemCount: 2,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            if (index == 0) {
              return Container(
                height: 98,
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: futureListOfStory,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      List<Story> _storyList = snapshot.data;
                      return ListView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: _storyList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return _storyAvatar(
                            height: 98,
                            width: 98,
                            story: _storyList.elementAt(index),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      print('error in Snapshot');
                      return Text('Error occured');
                    } else {
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
                  },
                ),
              );
            }
            return Container(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                future: futureListOfPost,
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    List<Post> _postList = snapshot.data;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      itemCount: _postList.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return _postWidget(post: _postList.elementAt(index));
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                },
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _postWidget({@required Post post}) {
    return Container(
      height: 500,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundImage: NetworkImage(post.profileImageUrl),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 8,
                    child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
                        child: Text(
                          post.username,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        )),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: Icon(
                      Feather.more_horizontal,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Container(
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Image(
                image: NetworkImage(post.postMediaUrl),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                        child: Icon(
                          post.isLiked ? Icons.favorite : Icons.favorite_border,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 28,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                        child: Icon(
                          FontAwesome.comment_o,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 28,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8),
                        child: Icon(
                          Feather.send,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 28,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Icon(
                    post.isSaved
                        ? FontAwesome.bookmark
                        : FontAwesome.bookmark_o,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: 28,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text('${post.likeCount} likes',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        )),
                    RichText(
                      text: TextSpan(
                        text: post.username,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                        children: [
                          TextSpan(
                            text: ' ${post.postCaption}',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'View all ${post.commentCount} comments',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.grey[500],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      '${Utils.getTimeDifference(post.postCreationDate)}',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[500]),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _storyAvatar({
    @required double height,
    @required double width,
    @required Story story,
  }) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 7.5),
      height: height - 30, //155,
      width: width - 30, //155,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            height: height - 30, //155,
            width: width - 30, //155,
            child: Center(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Container(
                      height: height - 30, // 150,
                      width: width - 30, //150,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: story.isSeen ? Colors.grey[500] : Colors.red,
                            width: 3,
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Container(
                      height: height - 40, //140,
                      width: width - 40, //140,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(story.imageUrl),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            story.username,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

'''[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/json/stories.json
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:225:7)

#1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:68:33)
#2      CachingAssetBundle.loadString. (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:166:56)
#3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:291:23)
#4      CachingAssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:166:27)
#5      FeedRepo.getFutureListOfStoryFromJson (package:alpha/modules/home/repositories/feed_repo.dart:9:26)
#6      _HomepageState.initState (package:alpha/pages/homeFeed.page.dart:25:35)
#7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
#8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
#9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widge<…>
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/json/posts.json
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:225:7)

#1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:68:33)
#2      CachingAssetBundle.loadString. (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:166:56)
#3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:291:23)
#4      CachingAssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:166:27)
#5      FeedRepo.getFutureListOfPostFromJson (package:alpha/modules/home/repositories/feed_repo.dart:19:26)
#6      _HomeScreenState.initState (package:alpha/pages/home_screen.dart:30:34)
#7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
#8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
#9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets<…>
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 5.0 pixels on the bottom.
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/json/stories.json
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:225:7)

#1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:68:33)
#2      CachingAssetBundle.loadString. (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:166:56)
#3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:291:23)
#4      CachingAssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:166:27)
#5      FeedRepo.getFutureListOfStoryFromJson (package:alpha/modules/home/repositories/feed_repo.dart:9:26)
#6      _HomepageState.initState (package:alpha/pages/homeFeed.page.dart:25:35)
#7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
#8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
#9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widge<…>
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Unable to load asset: assets/json/posts.json
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:225:7)

#1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:68:33)
#2      CachingAssetBundle.loadString. (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:166:56)
#3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:291:23)
#4      CachingAssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:166:27)
#5      FeedRepo.getFutureListOfPostFromJson (package:alpha/modules/home/repositories/feed_repo.dart:19:26)
#6      _HomeScreenState.initState (package:alpha/pages/home_screen.dart:30:34)
#7      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
#8      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
#9      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets<…>
'''

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "username": "Desuka00",
      "profileImageUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/1.jpeg',",
      "postMediaUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/1.jpeg',",
      "isLiked": true,
      "isSaved": false,
      "likeCount": 1000,
      "postCaption": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
      "commentCount": 80,
      "postCreationDate": 1591091160201
    },
    {
      "username": "Desuka01",
      "profileImageUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/2.jpeg',",
      "postMediaUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/2.jpeg',",
      "isLiked": false,
      "isSaved": true,
      "likeCount": 500,
      "postCaption": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
      "commentCount": 50,
      "postCreationDate": 1591091160201
    },
    {
      "username": "Desuka02",
      "profileImageUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/3.jpeg',",
      "postMediaUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/3.jpeg',",
      "isLiked": true,
      "isSaved": true,
      "likeCount": 200,
      "postCaption": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
      "commentCount": 80,
      "postCreationDate": 1591091160201
    },
    {
      "username": "Desuka03",
      "profileImageUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/4.jpeg',",
      "postMediaUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/4.jpeg',",
      "isLiked": false,
      "isSaved": false,
      "likeCount": 55,
      "postCaption": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
      "commentCount": 80,
      "postCreationDate": 1591091160201
    },
    {
      "username": "Desuka04",
      "profileImageUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/5.jpeg',",
      "postMediaUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/5.jpeg',",
      "isLiked": true,
      "isSaved": true,
      "likeCount": 1,
      "postCaption": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
      "commentCount": 5,
      "postCreationDate": 1591091160201
    },
    {
      "username": "Desuka05",
      "profileImageUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/6.jpeg',",
      "postMediaUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/6.jpeg',",
      "isLiked": true,
      "isSaved": true,
      "likeCount": 11,
      "postCaption": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
      "commentCount": 80,
      "postCreationDate": 1591091160201
    },
    {
      "username": "Desuka06",
      "profileImageUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/7.jpeg',",
      "postMediaUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/7.jpeg',",
      "isLiked": false,
      "isSaved": true,
      "likeCount": 78,
      "postCaption": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
      "commentCount": 88,
      "postCreationDate": 1591091160201
    },
    {
      "username": "Desuka07",
      "profileImageUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/8.jpeg',",
      "postMediaUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/8.jpeg',",
      "isLiked": true,
      "isSaved": false,
      "likeCount": 11,
      "postCaption": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
      "commentCount": 95,
      "postCreationDate": 1591091160201
    },
    {
      "username": "Desuka08",
      "profileImageUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/9.jpeg',",
      "postMediaUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/9.jpeg',",
      "isLiked": true,
      "isSaved": false,
      "likeCount": 100,
      "postCaption": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
      "commentCount": 80,
      "postCreationDate": 1591091160201
    },
    {
      "username": "Desuka09",
      "profileImageUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/10.jpeg',",
      "postMediaUrl": "'https://gitlab.com/2Shours/alphapic/-/raw/master/11.jpeg',",
      "isLiked": true,
      "isSaved": false,
      "likeCount": 100,
      "postCaption": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.",
      "commentCount": 80,
      "postCreationDate": 1591091160201
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you add its path to pubspec?

Comment: can you post your sample json

Comment: @SagarAcharya  already Edit for you in post bro.

Comment: @M.M.Hasibuzzaman I didn't Understand, What do you prefer to add ?

Comment: He means to say that the local json that you are using have you defined the the path for that in the pub spec.yaml file.

Comment: @SagarAcharya i m so Embarrassed here, i forgot to add in pubspec.yaml  ;-;